# React HOC component in typescript gives warnings (converting from non-typescript)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, create-react-app, higher-order-components

I'm having the following simple HOC component in react + typescript.

```
export const withFirebase = <P extends object>(
  Component: React.ComponentType<P>
) =>
  class WithFirebase extends React.Component<P> {
    render() {
      return (
        <FirebaseContext.Consumer>
          {firebase => <Component {...this.props} firebase={firebase} />}
        </FirebaseContext.Consumer>
      )
    }
  }

export default FirebaseContext
```

I'm converting this component from non-type script to a typescript function but ESlint gives me the following errors: Missing return type on function. What am I missing here? Should I write my HOC component differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried to provide return type on function?

```
export const withFirebase = <P extends object>(
  Component: React.ComponentType<P>
): React.ComponentType<P> =>
```

Comment: Also you might consider turning this eslint rule off: `"@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": "off"`

Comment: thanks! that works. I wonder why it also gives me this error on the render function. Maybe I just need to just turn it off in my rules since eslint seems to eager. Wonder what the best practice is here

Comment: Well probably it wants render function to have explicit return parameter as well. Something like this: `render(): ReactNode {`

Comment: Best practice is to put explicit types everywhere where return type is not obvious from context. This rule enforces to put it absolutely everywhere, which might make your code too verbose.

Comment: Thank you so much for the information! I understand now. Just wonderng why it even gives me a warning on this line  {firebase => <Component {...this.props} firebase={firebase} />} (firebsae =>). but I will make sure my eslint is not so strict